# How to pass a null variable to a SQL Stored Procedure from C#.net code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im calling a SQL stored procedure from a piece of C#.net code:

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(sqlConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, STORED_PROC_NAME, sqlParameters);
```

where the `sqlParameters` variable is defined as:

```
        SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[SQL_NUMBER_PARAMETERS];

        Log.Logger.Debug(string.Format("Running proc: {0} ", STORED_PROC_NAME));

        SqlParameters[0] = new SqlParameter("fieldID", SqlDbType.BigInt );
        SqlParameters[0].Value = fieldID;
        SqlParameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

I need to now pass in another two parameters to this Stored Proc, (both are of type `SqlDateTime`), which are going to *NULL* in this case.

Thanks,

IN

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
SqlParameters[1] = new SqlParameter("Date1", SqlDbType.SqlDateTime);
SqlParameters[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
SqlParameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

...then copy for the second.

Answer (score 30):

Use `DBNull.Value`  Better still, make your stored procedure parameters have defaults of NULL. Or use a `Nullable<DateTime>` parameter if the parameter will sometimes be a valid DateTime object

Comment: You get a +1 for being the first person to mention the default parameter for the stored proc possibility.

Answer (score 14):

You can pass the `DBNull.Value` into the parameter's .Value property:

```
    SqlParameters[0] = new SqlParameter("LedgerID", SqlDbType.BigInt );
    SqlParameters[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Just adjust for your two DateTime parameters, obviously - just showing how to use the `DBNull.Value` property value here.

Marc

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but here's a fairly clean way to create a nullable parameter:

```
new SqlParameter("@note", (object) request.Body ?? DBNull.Value);
```

If request.Body has a value, then it's value is used. If it's null, then DbNull.Value is used.

Answer (score 8):

I use a method to convert to DBNull if it is null

```
    // Converts to DBNull, if Null
    public static object ToDBNull(object value)
    {
        if (null != value)
            return value;
        return DBNull.Value;
    }
```

So when setting the parameter, just call the function

```
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NoteNo", LibraryHelper.ToDBNull(NoteNo)));
```

This will ensure any nulls, get changed to DBNull.Value, else it will stay the same.

Comment: that's good solution i changed static method to extension method for objects `public static object ToDbNull(this object value)
        {
            if (null != value)
                return value;
            return DBNull.Value;
        }`

Comment: Except that a DateTime isn't a nullable type, so this won't work for DateTime (as specified in the question), or for any other non-nullable value types, unless you declare all you vars to be Nullable<T> which doesn't seem a particularly good approach.

Comment: It might be simpler, rathar than having this extension method, to simply use the null coalescing operator: `new SqlParameter("@NoteNo", NoteNo as object ?? System.DbNull)`

Answer (score 2):

try this! syntax less lines and even more compact! don't forget to add the properties you want to add with this approach!

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter{SqlValue=(object)username??DBNull.Value,ParameterName="user" }  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SQLParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RetailerID", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
    If p_RetailerID.Length = 0 Or p_RetailerID = "0" Then
        SQLParam.Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        SQLParam.Value = p_RetailerID
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of the parameter is "Id" in your SQL stored procedure, and the C# function you're using to call the database stored procedure is name of type `int?`. Given that, following might solve your issue :

```
public void storedProcedureName(Nullable<int> id, string name)
{
    var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
                new SqlParameter("Id", id) :
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Id", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = DBNull.Value };

    // to be continued...
```