# Entity Frameworks ExecuteSqlCommand Null parameter giving error

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5. When I call a stored procedure where the parameter is null, I get

> "stored proc" expects parameter x which was not supplied.

I need to be able to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` even if its parameters are null:

```
 Sub SaveMANUALPosting(ByVal ExpiryDate AS DateTime)

    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec spLC_STAGEPostingLCAmendment @argExpiryDate", 
     New SqlParameter("argExpiryDate", If((IsNothing(ExpiryDate)), DBNull.Value, ExpiryDate)))

 end Sub
```

The above code does not work of course, but illustrates what I am trying to do. How can I pass a `DbNull` value if the incoming parameter is null?

Comment: where is the error occurring? Are you sure your stored procedure is allowing for a null parameter?  This sounds very similar to what happens if you try to execute a stored procedure WITH a null param, but the SP does not accept null params

Comment: DbNull.Value not working ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207404/how-to-pass-a-null-variable-to-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-c-net-code

Comment: Sorry deleted my answer... thought was related to something else and I don't know VB syntax to assist with what @YuliamChandra suggested

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work by creating a function.  Here is the code:

```
 Sub SaveMANUALPosting(ByVal ExpiryDate AS DateTime)

     db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec spLC_STAGEPostingLCAmendment @argExpiryDate", 
      New SqlParameter("argExpiryDate", FormatDBValue(ExpiryDate))

 end Sub

 Protected Function FormatDBValue(ByVal pIn As Object) As Object
    If IsNothing(pIn) Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        Return pIn
    End If
 End Function
```

The function will return either dbnull.value or the parmeter value if it is not null.  The second parm of "SqlParameter" expects an object, so the function provides that.

Thanks for the replies.  Got me thinking...