# Passing Multiple Table valued parameters to stored Procedure , some parameters may empty

Tags: c#, sql

I have a stored procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
```

`@Parm1 Temp1TableType READONLY,`
`@Param2 Temp2TableType READONLY,`
`@Param3 Temp3TableType READONLY,`
`@Parm4 Temp4TableType READONLY,`
`@Parm5 Temp5TableType READONLY`

I  call this stored procedure using dapper and passing an anonymous object as the param  to the SP like

```
Param : new { @Parm1 = dt1,@Parm2=dt2,@Parm3=dt3, @Parm4=dt4, @Parm5=dt5}
```

But these `dt1,dt2,dt3,dt4 and dt5`  tables may  be null in some cases depending on certain scenarios. How we can  call the SP then.. Here Dapper is used
Please help...

Comment: So, what is your problem, did you tried to pass and got some error?

Comment: Yes when we are trying to  pass NULL value  or empty data table exception occurs .

Comment: Is there any possible way that we can create an anonymous object dynamically..

Comment: Just set what you think might have a null value when declaring the parameters.
For example `@test INT = NULL`

Comment: but it is a table valued parameter , so when we set null that attribute need not be sent to Sp. Supporse   dt1 is null then Param will be like   Param : new { @Parm2=dt2,@Parm3=dt3, @Parm4=dt4, @Parm5=dt5}

Comment: Is this what you want? [How to pass a null variable to a SQL Stored Procedure from C#.net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207404/how-to-pass-a-null-variable-to-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-c-net-code)

Comment: Table-valued parameters cannot be `NULL` and do not allow `NULL`. To call a sproc without filling the table, the parameter must be omitted entirely (or else, I suppose, an appropriate empty collection must be used). You could use `DynamicParameters` for this rather than an anonymous object.

Comment: Yeah Yes we have to omit that parameter. here we are using anonymous object. So how we can achieve it ?

Comment: With an anonymous object, you can't. It's a class in the background, not a `dynamic` or `Dictionary` where you can add or remove properties at will. You'd have to use massive if-else statements to selectively create the correct type -- leaving out the parameter means leaving out the property, and with 5 parameters there are 32 combinations. Selectively pass the parameters using `DynamicParameters`, or else never use `null` but empty tables of the appropriate structure.

Comment: Here can we use dictionary and then cast the dictionary to anonymous type?